# import error in embedding python with boost python

Tags: c++, boost-python

I have following code

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    namespace python = boost::python;
    try {
        python::object main = python::import("sample");
    } catch(...) {
        PyErr_Print();
        PyErr_Clear();
    }
}
```

I get following error:

```
ImportError: No module named sample
```

I put my sample.py at the same directory as this program.

Comment: When debugging import issues, it can be helpful to set the [`PYTHONVERBOSE`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONVERBOSE) environment variable to `2`.  This will cause Python to print where python is trying to import files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because python::import is not looking inside the current directory. I know two ways to solve it:

Set the PYTHONPATH to look inside your current directory (linux):

```
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`:$PYTHONPATH
```

or...

Set the python search module path inside your code (also it provides a better explanation about the issue that you've found out):
[How does import work with Boost.Python from inside python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285384/how-does-import-work-with-boost-python-from-inside-python-files)